# Why does my CSS tooltip push my other content down?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, z-index

I have a CSS tooltip, with CSS3 fade in, with z-indexes set to 999. When I hover over the link, the tooltip itself pushes my other content down, it's meant to be above, not inline, although I've used a span and converted it to block..

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PcUPQ/) is an example of what I'm going for, how can I stop it from pushing the content down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Display:block` doesn't take an element out of the page flow, it simply pushes it onto its own new line.  Using `position:absolute` - as recommended by other posters - should work for you.  `Position:absolute` will set a position (such as `top:0px; left:20px;`) to the browser window overall unless there is a parent with `position:relative` set (which would then become the point of reference).  An example of this second type would be positioning a link exactly 30px from the right within a given content div - regardless of where that div is placed on the page.

`Position:relative` can be used to position an element relative to its original position in the natural page flow, and it leaves a space where the element would have been.  `Position:fixed` can be used for elements that should not move when the page is scrolled (such as a fixed navigation bar, page branding, or footer).  `Position:static` is the default position setting, and should be used when you need to override another position type.

If you're using a span for the tooltip text within another element - you'll likely want to set the parent element to `position:relative`, and set the inner span to `position:absolute`.  You'll need to set a top and left value to adjust where exactly your tooltip text falls (ie. above or below the parent element, to the left or the right).

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Absolute position the tooltip (set the container's position to `relative` and the absolute position will be relative to the container).

Comment: I honestly thought this wouldnt work but it did, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure the tooltip css position value it absolute? (or at least not static).